# JList with toggable group headers

Tags: java, swing, jlist, listcellrenderer

Is it possible to do something like the following image in Java?

I understand that I would need to be using a multi columned list, with a custom cell renderer, in order to show the images of each list element.  But my question is regards to Grouping the list elements, and using group headers...

[image: image of a grouped list view]

As you can see from the image above this comes from windows explorer and is exactly the type of grouped list view that I would be looking to do with a JList in Java.

Comment: Maybe [`org.netbeans.swing.outline.Outline`](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/4446/file-browser-gui/4447#4447)?

Comment: @trashgod Thats not really what I am looking for...  Thats for trees/tables.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think I would use a `JTable` in this situation.

First of all, I'd use a simple `JPanel` with [DesignGridLayout](http://designgridlayout.java.net/), something like the example demonstrated in [DesignGridLayout showdown application](http://designgridlayout.java.net/examples.jnlp), section "**Dynamic Layouts**", example "**Example 4 - Same with indented rows**".

In that example you'd have to change the icons used for the outline effect (triangles instead of chevrons in the example).

Then, I would create a `DrivePane` deriving from `JPanel`, that would contain the drive icon as a `JLabel` (with no text), the drive name as a `JLabel`, the size as a `JProgress` bar, the size as a `JLabel`. I would probably use `GridBagLayout` as the `LayoutManager` for `DrivePane`. That component would be used for every drive to show.

Comment: 'I would use GridBagLayout', coming from _you_? Probably should remove DesignGrid from my list of highly recommended managers if it can't do this easily ... grinning :-)

Comment: @kleopatra hehe very good ;-) I am all for "use the right tool for the job" and I don't think DesignGrid would be able to handle the drive panel which is a bit specific.